# Issue making a response from a google form showing error ""TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")""

Tags: google-apps-script, typeerror, google-forms

In Google Forms, I am attempting to create an email response that includes a case number that is generated in the form responses (column titled code) but unfortunately, I have come across the error:

> typeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")

I am a complete novice regarding this but I have set the trigger function and am given this error in the email that is sent in a reply.

Find a copy of the responses docs below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w8cUkErljf6JzQm9q5aFwa-m9jX4o5qrAg5K7ib9Keg/edit?usp=sharing

This is the code I'm using:

```
function myFunction(e){
var userName = e.namedValues.Name;
var userEmail = e.namedValues.Tag;
var date = e.namedValues.Timestamp;
var subject = e.namedValues.Code;
var message = "Thanks, " + userName + " for submiting your data remember to take note of your Case number "+ subject + "You'll need this to for you or the customer to find the case again" +date;
MailApp.sendEmail (userEmail, subject, message);}
```

I expect it to generate an email, use the code as a subject and include it the text in the body.

Comment: It sounds like your in the Form Script Editor rather than Spreadsheet script editor.

Comment: I am should I be doing this from the spreadsheet editor

Comment: I'm not sure what you said.  What editor are you working in?

Answer (score 0):

### Different Google Applications can have triggers with the same name, but different event objects.

To access the latest form response you need the trigger `onFormsubmit()`, which can be both a Google Sheets and Google Form trigger.

> `e.namedValues` is a Google **Sheets** `onFormsubmit()` [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), while a Google
>   **Form**  `onFormsubmit()` event object would be `e.response`.

### You have two options:

1. Bind your Apps Script to the Spreadsheet where your form responses are being saved and access the responses with `e.namedValues` as intended
2. Bind your Apps Script to the Form itself and access the responses with `e.response` as following:

```
var userName = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();
var userEmail= e.response.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
...
```

Keep in mind that `onFormsubmit()` is an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers) Trigger.

Comment: I have set up a trigger on the g-suite developer's hub and I get an email with the above error message when the form is submitted

Comment: Did you set up the trigger by going from the Apps Script UI on Edit-> Current project's triggers->create new trigger?